# PHP/Mysql Search - Case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following PHP and MySql to fetch rows from a table,

```
$search_word=$_GET['search_word'];
$search_word_new=mysql_escape_string($search_word);
$search_word_fix=str_replace(" ","%",$search_word_new);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE content LIKE '%$search_word_fix%' ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20");
```

The 'content' field is a TEXT field containing tweets.

The problem I have is if I search '**S**tackoverflow' I get all the results containing 'Stackoverflow' but no results when the text is '**s**tackoverflow'. Basically the search is case sensitive.

Is it possible to change the query or PHP so when searching for 'Stackoverflow' both upper and lower case results are returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
$search_word_fix=strtolower(str_replace(" ","%",$search_word_new));
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE lower(content) LIKE '%$search_word_fix%' ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20");
```

- I've added `strtolower` to make
  `$search_word_fix` all lower case.
- And in the where clause I've changed
  `content` to `lower(content)` so that
  I compare with lowercase of
  `content`.

You could have made both these changes in the query as suggested in other answer.

Comment: Simplest solution for me as a PHP novice.

Comment: Simplest != best.  This will take no advantage of any possible index, and is quite likely slower. (said the pompous idiot who was actually just saddened by the fact nobody seems to care about the oh-so-easy case-insensitive collation in MySQL).

Answer (score 4):

Force the cases of both the search term and the column value:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE LOWER(content) LIKE LOWER('%$search_word_fix%') ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE UPPER(content) LIKE UPPER('%$search_word_fix%') ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

The 'proper' way to do it is to set it to case-insensitive collation:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (col1 varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin,col2 varchar(24) COLLATE  utf8_general_ci);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

DB 5.1.49-1-log:test  mysql> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('stackoverflow','stackoverflow');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

DB 5.1.49-1-log:test  mysql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col1 LIKE 'Stackoverflow';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

DB 5.1.49-1-log:test  mysql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col2 LIKE 'Stackoverflow';
+---------------+---------------+
| col1          | col2          |
+---------------+---------------+
| stackoverflow | stackoverflow |
+---------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

DB 5.1.49-1-log:test  mysql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col1 COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE 'Stackoverflow';
+---------------+---------------+
| col1          | col2          |
+---------------+---------------+
| stackoverflow | stackoverflow |
+---------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Don't use the `COLLATE` clause unless you simply can't change the column's collation -- You can't use the index.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `COLLATION` of the column in question (`content`) to be case insensitive, such as `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Doing the case folding in PHP is costly and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

mysql> SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable WHERE username = 'test980';
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable WHERE username = 'TEST980';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MySQL columns can be made case-sensitive by creating them with the binary keyword. I suspect this is your problem. You can modify the column not to be binary or change your query to:

SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable WHERE UCASE(username) = 'TEST980';

which effectively makes string comparisons case insensitive despite the
Binary character set chosen.

Comment: `BINARY` and `UCASE` are costly because the index cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about choosing the best collation when creating MySql database.

- utf8_unicode_ci is useful if you want to sort for example german character set accurately but it's slow.
- utf8_general_ci is by default the standard when creating MySQL database character set utf8 and it's the fastest, but not case sensitive.
- Rule of thumb: Use always utf8_general_ci on MySQL and collate utf8_bin if case sensitive required OR use SELECT BINARY in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Note if you are using another language and you are using "strtolower()" it doesnt convert special characters(non english letters) to lowercase this will do the job mb_strtolower($text, 'utf8');